# Need to get multiple name with one checkbox

Tags: php, html

i'm blocked on my code.
I'm trying since two day to get to send through a $_POST an ID that i get from my database. 
Let me show you my code so you would be able to understand better :

```html
<form action="traitementSuppr.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" name="suppression">
  <?php 
   if (isset($_GET['id_suppr'])) {
      $rowp = getProfilById($dbh, $_GET['id_suppr']);
      $LogicielProfil = SelectLogi($dbh, $_GET['id_suppr']);
      $JobSecteur = SelectInfo($dbh,$_GET['id_suppr']); 
   }
   echo "<br>". $rowp['nom'] ."<br>" ;
   echo $rowp['prenom'] ."<br>";
   echo "<br>coucou voici la liste de Job : <br>";
   foreach ($JobSecteur as $key2) 
      {
          $poste1 = getPosteById($dbh, $key2['id_poste']);
          $secteur1 = getSectorById($dbh, $key2['id_secteur']);
          echo "<label><input type='checkbox' id='Job' 
    value='" . $key2['id_poste']."' name='Poste[]'> Supprimer</label><br>". $poste1['nom_poste'] ." dans le secteur ". $secteur1['nom_secteur'] ."<br>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='idsuppr' value=". $key2['id_secteur']  .">";
      }
  ?>
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Valider</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Sorry, most of my data are in french.
So i'm trying to send id_secteur which is a the end of my foreach.
However the fact is i dont know how to do it, and i need it absolutely when the chekbox is checked. Any idea with how I could send it trough my $_post ?

I'm available to give more information ! :D

Comment: Within your `foreach` loop you are generating inputs with the same name so you will only ever get one value for `$_POST['idsuppr']` no matter how many iterations there are. Try changing `name='idsuppr'` to `name='idsuppr[]'` which should get you closer to what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to really understand what you really want but you could set the id of the secteur in the checkbox name :

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" id="Job' . $key2['id_secteur'] . '" value="' . $key2['id_poste']. '" name="Poste[' . $key2['id_secteur'] . ']">';
```

this way your $_POST['Poste'] would be an array with the secteur in the keys and the poste in the values.

I also changed your checkbox ID value since you can't have all the checkboxes having the same id.